# WordPress | WP_Query does not return anything with s=a

Tags: wp-query

I have the following code:

```
$data = new WP_Query('s=a');
```

and the print_r returns the following data:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [s] => a
            [error] => 
            [m] => 0
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [static] => 
            [pagename] => 
            [page_id] => 0
            [second] => 
            [minute] => 
            [hour] => 
            [day] => 0
            [monthnum] => 0
            [year] => 0
            [w] => 0
            [category_name] => 
            [tag] => 
            [cat] => 
            [tag_id] => 
            [author_name] => 
            [feed] => 
            [tb] => 
            [paged] => 0
            [comments_popup] => 
            [meta_key] => 
            [meta_value] => 
            [preview] => 
            [sentence] => 
            [fields] => 
            [menu_order] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
            [suppress_filters] => 
            [cache_results] => 1
            [update_post_term_cache] => 1
            [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
            [post_type] => any
            [posts_per_page] => 10
            [nopaging] => 
            [comments_per_page] => 50
            [no_found_rows] => 
            [search_terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                )

            [order] => DESC
        )

    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => AND
        )

    [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => 
        )

    [post_count] => 0
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [found_posts] => 0
    [max_num_pages] => 0
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_archive] => 
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 
    [is_search] => 1
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 
    [is_404] => 
    [is_comments_popup] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 
    [query_vars_hash] => 1015947de489d0153582586bded7c016
    [query_vars_changed] => 
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [query] => Array
        (
            [s] => a
        )

    [request] => SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2
    [posts] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

What is wrong with this query and does not return any data ? Also take a look at the "request" where it is `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay here. My request:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%a%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%a%')))  AND (wp_posts.post_password = '')  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I tried changing the `a` to other strings and it worked the same - the query looked for posts where the title or the content contained that string.

I tried it from an external file. My file contents:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );  
require('wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'); 

$a = new WP_Query( 's=a' );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $a );
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This is marked as "accepted" but I'd like to know why the OP was getting `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2` and then, apparently, isn't getting that anymore.

Comment: I would like to know too...